# How to read utf-8 csv Chinese file in python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I have a csv file which the content is all in Chinese (except for headers). Since I want to read the file as dictionary (where col headers are keys), I did the following:

```
import csv
d = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv', 'rU')

final = []
for row in d:
    final.append(row)
```

But when I try to access the values, the values are all broken and shows up like this:

```
'\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xba\xb7\xe8\xa1\x8d\xe6\x8a\xa4\xe7\x90\x86\xe7\xab\x99'
```

So the `file.csv` is a UTF-8 csv file (originally made in Excel and saved as xlsx but later saved as csv file). How can I read this file in python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xba\xb7\xe8\xa1\x8d\xe6\x8a\xa4\xe7\x90\x86\xe7\xab\x99'` is the UTF-8 bytes of your Chinese text. To get unicode, do `text = your_bytes.decode('utf8')`.

Unfortunately, the Python 2 csv module does not play nice with unicode. You can try to parse it as bytes and decode later. This would not normally be good practice, but might be your best bet.

You can also use pandas for your CSV needs, which supports unicode properly

import io

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: f = io.StringIO(u"""foo,bar,baz,qux
   ...: 美國精,神醫學,學會是,美國精神
   ...: 科醫生,的專業,組織在,行內具有
   ...: 全球性,的影響,力現有,約名會員""")

In [4]: dataframe = pd.read_csv(f)

In [5]: dataframe['bar']
Out[5]: 
0    神醫學
1    的專業
2    的影響
Name: bar, dtype: object

In [6]: dataframe.loc[1, :]
Out[6]: 
foo     科醫生
bar     的專業
baz     組織在
qux    行內具有
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

---

As a reminder, just in case you shared the confusion some have, the `U` in your mode is for universal newlines, not unicode. To read a text file as unicode, use `io.open`. (Note: the csv module won't work with such a file.)

Comment: Hi, I tried my_byte.decode('utf8'), but I'm getting the result u'\u4e0a\u6d77\u5eb7\u884d\u62a4\u7406\u7ad9', is this right?

Comment: @song0089 Yes, that is the repr of a unicode string. You can then use it wherever text is used. If you print it to a terminal, it should display as Chinese glyphs, if you had it to a GUI, it should render the right thing for the user, etc.